# Получение значение Input и Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

При введении данных в поле input внизу получаю то, что вписали. Нужно, чтобы перед вводом внизу появлялось значение VALUE, а после редактирования INPUT появлялся новый текст. Подскажите, как такое можно сделать?

```
<input type="text" class="mytext" value="Пример">
<p id="contenInput"></p>
<script>
$(document).ready ( function(){
$(".mytext").keyup(function() {
 $('#contenInput').text($(".mytext").val());
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Надо чтобы при вводе в "онлайн" режиме выводился текст в тот де <p>?

Comment: @RedWoolf да, в режиме реального времени

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready ( function(){
  $(".mytext").bind("change keyup input", function() {
    $('#contenInput').text($(".mytext").val());
  });
  $('#contenInput').text($(".mytext").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="mytext" value="Пример">
<p id="contenInput"></p>
```

Comment: Но значение VALUE появляется только после того, как нажимаю на область input

Comment: @bakusite объясните чего Вы хотите, что значит "чтобы перед вводом внизу появлялось ..."

Comment: Чтобы при открытии страницы и в самом Input и под в ним в <p id="contenInput"></p> было значение VALUE, но после его изменения менялось на другой текст

Comment: да) Отлично, работает!

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать по интервалу

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="mytext" value="Пример">
<p id="contenInput"></p>
<script>
  $(document).ready ( function(){
     setInterval(function() {
      $('#contenInput').text($(".mytext").val());
     }, 100);
  });
</script>
```